# Complexity including randomness

Tags: time-complexity, computer-science, complexity-theory

I have the following three loops:

```
for i in range(m)
    for j in range(n)
        r = random(0,l)
        for k in range(r)
            
        l = l-r
```

and I am wondering what the complexity is here, does the last one equate to `O(1)`? The first two loops should be `O(m*n)`. `l,m,n` are of course integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original value of  sets a maximum to the *total* number of times the inner loop can make an iteration. Put in another way, the sum of *all* values that  will get, cannot exceed the original value of .

So for the outer two loops we have θ(), and add to that the worst case for the total number of iterations of the inner loop, and we get a worst case time complexity of O(+).

NB: the *best* case occurs when `random` always returns 0. In that case we get θ() as time complexity.